# I have built a Tic Tac Toe Game but there is a bug where there is no way to verify if a player has won and then break out of the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

```
def DrawField(field):
    for row in range(5):  
        if row%2 == 0:
            practicalrow = int(row/2)
            for column in range(5): 
                if column%2 == 0:
                    practicalcolumn = int(column/2)
                    if column !=4:
                        print(field[practicalcolumn][practicalrow],end="")
                    else:
                        print(field[practicalcolumn][practicalrow])
                else:
                    print("|",end="")
        else:
            print("-----")

Player = 1
CurrentField = [[" ", " ", " "],[" ", " ", " "],[" ", " ", " "]]
print(CurrentField)
DrawField(CurrentField)
while(True):
    print("Players Turn:", Player)
    MoveRow = int(input("PLease enter the row\n"))
    MoveCol = int(input("PLeasae enter the column\n"))
    if Player == 1:
        if CurrentField[MoveCol][MoveRow] == " ":
            CurrentField[MoveCol][MoveRow] = "X"
            #make move for player 1
            Player = 2
        else:
            continue
    else:
        if CurrentField[MoveCol][MoveRow] == " ":
            CurrentField[MoveCol][MoveRow] = "O"
            #make move for player 2
            Player = 1
        else:
            continue

    DrawField(CurrentField)
```

so, here is the code of gthe tictactoe game, i had a bug where players were able to rewrite each others moves. i eventually fixed that but another bug is that the loop doesn't break once a player wins. also, if there could be a way to ask for a replay after a player wins
Some trivial information: the spaces in each sub-list of the currentField list refer to each column of the game board respectively.

Comment: You should post your code here so we can see what you have so far

Comment: You need to add some code you did so we can see how to help you with your issue

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell how you verify if a side wins or not, and if you have done it, I will assume you will since that isnt the topic of your question.

For your issue of breaking out the `while` loop you can use `break`, for example like this:

```
while True:
    if has_won == true:
        break

    ####other code
```

That if statement would be the first check in the while loop, its important its at the start because if it was at the end the turn would take place and the check if the game is over for the previous turn would only just happen.

The `break` can be used for a `while` and `for` loops as it just breaks outside the loop at that point